# Can Flash text and images be changed without modifying source FLA?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

Generally speaking, let's say I create a small, simple FLA animation that simply takes the text "Take a look at Tuesday's Deals!" and moves it across the screen. I then build and generate the SWF file.

Is it somehow possible to create this FLA file so that, once the SFW is built, I can change the text without having to open the FLA and recreating the SWF?

Can it be done with images? For example, I create a FLA with a 50x50px image that moves across the screen. Can I switch to another 50x50px image without having to rebuild the SWF?

The reason I ask is because I can create the initial FLA, but I won't be able to modify. The person that will deal with modifying the text and/or image doesn't know Flash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load content dynamically at run-time. The design of your application should be such that it loads an xml file or something of that nature to specify what artwork/text to use.

So you need to load an XML file , or some other type of data.

Then dynamically load audio/artwork based on that data.

You can even make the app so that it can load other .swf files with new content.

Comment: Assuming I have the SWF in server A, is it possible that the SWF read the XML file in server B?

So the SWF would be in the newspaper server, but the XML file would be in my server.

Comment: Sure, that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line assembler/disassembler to do this. Here are the two command line assembler/disassembler I know.

http://www.nowrap.de/flasm

http://swfmill.org/

Disassemble the swf using either one of this, you will get text file.

In your case you can define a variable for text and find and replace the text.

And finally assemble it a swf.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to the swf containing information to be used.

```
http://www.mysite.com/banner/banner.swf?text="my text"&image="image1"    

var flashVars:Object = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var text:String = flashVars["text"];
var imagetype:String = flashVars["image"];
```

In the code you treat the data to be received.